# How to use the WHMCS API without actually displaying WHMCS?

Tags: php, mysql, whmcs

Is there any way in which i can use the WHMCS API without displaying WHMCS to the clients and users.
I want my PHP scripts to first create a WHMCS client, add an order for the client and then copy some files to the client's directory.
But i don't want my clients to be able to login to their WHMCS panel or even be able to see the WHMCS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WHMCS has something called `External API` that will help you.

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.whmcs.com/API). But for what you need yo should do this:

**Connect to the API**

```
$url = "http://www.yourdomain.com/includes/api.php"; # URL to WHMCS API file goes here
$username = "Admin"; # Admin username goes here
$password = "demoxyz"; # Admin password goes here
```

**Add the Client**

```
$postfields = array();
$postfields["username"] = $username;
$postfields["password"] = md5($password);
$postfields["action"] = "addclient"; 
$postfields["firstname"] = "Test";
$postfields["lastname"] = "User";
$postfields["companyname"] = "WHMCS";
$postfields["email"] = "demo@whmcs.com";
$postfields["address1"] = "123 Demo Street";
$postfields["city"] = "Demo";
$postfields["state"] = "Florida";
$postfields["postcode"] = "AB123";
$postfields["country"] = "US";
$postfields["phonenumber"] = "123456789";
$postfields["password2"] = "demo";
$postfields["customfields"] = base64_encode(serialize(array("1"=>"Google")));
$postfields["currency"] = "1";

$query_string = "";
foreach ($postfields AS $k=>$v) $query_string .= "$k=".urlencode($v)."&";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$jsondata = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) die("Connection Error: ".curl_errno($ch).' - '.curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);

$arr = json_decode($jsondata); # Decode JSON String

print_r($arr); # Output XML Response as Array
```

**Add the Order**

```
$postfields = array();
$postfields["username"] = $username;
$postfields["password"] = md5($password);
$postfields["action"] = "addorder";
$postfields["clientid"] = "1";
$postfields["pid"] = "1";
$postfields["domain"] = "whmcs.com";
$postfields["billingcycle"] = "monthly";
$postfields["addons"] = "1,3,9";
$postfields["customfields"] = base64_encode(serialize(array("1"=>"Google")));
$postfields["domaintype"] = "register";
$postfields["regperiod"] = "1";
$postfields["paymentmethod"] = "mailin";

$query_string = "";
foreach ($postfields AS $k=>$v) $query_string .= "$k=".urlencode($v)."&";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$jsondata = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) die("Connection Error: ".curl_errno($ch).' - '.curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);

$arr = json_decode($jsondata); # Decode JSON String

print_r($arr); # Output XML Response as Array
```

Then you can copy the files to the client's directory. Hope it helps!

Comment: That creates order without addons.